# In $\mathbb{F}[x]$, $(f(x)) \subseteq I$ if any only if $I=(g(x))$ for some monic $g$ that divides $f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $f(x)$ be a monic polynomial in $\mathbb{F} [x]$. I need to show that $(f(x))\subseteq I$ if and only if $I=(g(x))$ for some monic polynomial $g$ that divides $f$. The reverse direction is clear. I am getting stuck on the forward direction. It certainly seems intuitively true. I know that $r\in (f(x))$ means that $r=p(x) f(x)$ for some $p(x) \in \mathbb{F} [x]$ and I must have that $r\in J$. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

The leading coefficient of $f$, call it $l(f)$, is $1$. If $f\in (g)$ then $f=gh$ so obviously $g$ divides $f$, and $l(f)=l(g)l(h)$ so $l(g),l(h)$ are units, ie. without loss of generality $l(g)=1$.

Conclude from that $\Bbb{F}[x]$ is a principal ideal domain: this is because $(u,v)=(\gcd(u,v))$, whence your ideal $I$ is principal $=(g)$ for some $g$.